# How to filter ngFor table rows with radio-button dynamically

Tags: angular, radio-button, ngfor

I have two(2) functions in my .ts file for two(2) different radio buttons that I am filtering ngfor table by date with. The two buttons called: "valid" and "invalid". The "invalid" radio-button filters the table and presents all rows that has end-date "less than current date", while the "valid" present all rows that has end-date "less and greater than current date".

Just now when I click on one of the radio-buttons, I got the correct rows but then when I go on to click the second radio-button, I got empty or zero row.

How do I complete the .ts code to make the table rows available (dynamic) regardless of the radio-button pressed? Below is my code:

**.html**

```
<div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="date" (click)="valid()" />
            <label class="form-check-label">Valid</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="date" (click)="invalid()"/>
            <label class="form-check-label">Invalid</label>
        </div>
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let myAccount of Account | filterBy: accountFilter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
            <td>{{ (p - 1) * count + i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.startDate}}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.endDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

**.ts**

```
Account = [];
currentDate = '';

valid() {
        this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.Account = this.Account.filter(data => {
            return data.startDate < this.currentDate  && data.endDate > this.currentDate});
    }

invalid() {
    this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd");
    this.Account = this.Account.filter(data => {
        return data.startDate < this.currentDate  && data.endDate <= this.currentDate});
}
```

How do I go about it so that my **Account = [ ]** still holds all the table rows while I just use the radio-buttons to filter or toggle the rows based on dates?

A even if I should later add a third radio-button called "ShowAll", it can then return all rows in the table.

Thanks

Comment: can you reproduce it in https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan Something similar to this is what I need: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-filter-pipe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html but now with radio-button...

Comment: Share your code in stackblitz with some dummy data which reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

in HTML file use **change** event instead of **click**.

```
<div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="date" (change)="valid($event)" />
            <label class="form-check-label">Valid</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="date" (change)="invalid($event)"/>
            <label class="form-check-label">Invalid</label>
        </div>
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let myAccount of Account | filterBy: accountFilter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
            <td>{{ (p - 1) * count + i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.startDate}}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.endDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried the change event but the result was still the same.. Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-filter-pipe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html is what I need, but with radio-button